# Trying to set-up Jest for a ReactJs project

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

Having created a React app, I've been given the following test (app.test.jsx):

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App';

it('renders without crashing', async () => {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  ReactDOM.render(
    <MemoryRouter>
      <App />
    </MemoryRouter>, div);
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
});
```

I've installed Jest, but when I try to run the test, I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: C:\ .. \ClientApp\src\App.test.jsx: Unexpected token (9:4)

   7 |   const div = document.createElement('div');
   8 |   ReactDOM.render(
>  9 |     <MemoryRouter>
     |     ^
  10 |       <App />
  11 |     </MemoryRouter>, div);
  12 |   await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));

  at Parser._raise (../../../../../../AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/jest-cli/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/location.js:241:45)
```

I imagine it's relevant, but the directory `src` does **not** exist under `@babel/parser`.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to what the issue might be (or, if it does relate to babel parser, how I can correctly install that library)?

EDIT:

jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    verbose: true,
};
```

Comment: Hi @stannage, what is your jest config?

Comment: I take it you are using babel to transpile your code. Are you using the babel react preset?

Comment: I didn't intentionally choose to use babel, I just set-up the default react app, and it seems to have chosen that.  I did try a babel preset in the jest.config.ts, but I then get the error: "Unknown option "presets" with value [["@babel/preset-env",..."